# Create bootable USB with multiple installers?

Tags: bootcamp, usb, disk-utility, startup, efi

I have a 64GB thumb drive and about a dozen or so installation ISOs I'd like to have on it.  I would like to be able to have a single partiton, so that if I boot to it I am given a GRUB-stle boot menu which will allow me to select which ISO to boot from. When I select an ISO, I want it to boot from that ISO on the thumb drive. Simple as that.

I have a 2011 MacBook Pro running OS X 10.12. What do I need to do to accomplish this task?

Comment: 1) how is that question specific about Apple? 2) you won't be able to do that with your USB drive; 3) if you'd like to boot from different iso images without burning them individually, get a rooted Android phone and use [DriveDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid)

Comment: 1) because I'm using an apple computer and I'm asking how to create this from said apple computer.  2) Watch me.  3) ew Android

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer each of your questions separately:

#### All on one partition

Not possible with the current state of technology. Apple's startup systems look for bootable *partitions*, not images. You'll have to partition your device if you want to put many systems on it.

#### GRUB-style boot menu and selecting ISO

Try using macOS' built-in *Startup Manager* by holding down Option on boot. This will show you a list of bootable partitions that you can boot your system from.

#### Installers

If you intend to put OS X/macOS installers on your partition, look into `createinstallmedia`. Provide the path to the installer under the option `--applicationpath` and the disk to put the installer on (and make bootable) under the option `--volume`. Example syntax as follows:

```
/Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app --volume /Volumes/somevolume
```

Comment: I think you kind of have the right idea, but I'm looking to make a USB that I can use on any system, Mac or PC, so I select "Boot to Sandisk Cruzer..." then I get a GRUB-style menu of my ISOs.  That's what I'm looking for.  And even if I had to partition the USB but could still get the GRUB menu with all the installers I'd be happy.

Comment: @Daniel I'm afraid you may have to consider using other software; but that may be out of the scope of this site. I'm afraid I don't have any experience in this field, usually I just use Startup Manager. Good luck! Please do post an answer here if and when you find a solution.

Comment: I definitely will. If I can find software capable of writing ISOs sequentially to the USB, I may do that and install GRUB

Answer (score -2):

what you ask is not possible: apple osx asks for a different bootable formatted partition compared to windows iso's.

Comment: You are missing my point by a great deal.  I'm trying to make an installer USB for multiple systems.